# Sorry, user nagios is not allowed to execute 'SCRIPT.sh' as root on <HOST>

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sudo, nagios

```
user1@<HOSTNAME>:~$ sudo -H -u nagios bash -c "sudo /usr/localcw/bin/check_disk.sh -w 10% -c 80% -p /boot"

Sorry, user nagios is not allowed to execute '/usr/localcw/bin/check_disk.sh -w 10% -c 80% -p /boot' as root on <HOSTNAME>.
```

---

```
user1@<HOSTNAME>:~$ sudo -H -u nagios bash -c "sudo /usr/localcw/bin/nagios_check_files_age.sh -f /var/lib/logrotate/status -c 3600  -w 3600"

FILE_AGE OK: /var/lib/logrotate/status is 1680 seconds old and 1626 bytes.[w=3600 , c=3600 s]
```

---

```
user1@<HOSTNAME>:~$ ls -l /usr/localcw/bin/check_disk.sh

-rwx------ 1 root root 6390 Mar  3 16:45 /usr/localcw/bin/check_disk.sh
```

---

```
user1@<HOSTNAME>:~$  ls -l /usr/localcw/bin/nagios_check_files_age.sh

-rwx------ 1 root root 2236 Nov 13 15:48 /usr/localcw/bin/nagios_check_files_age.sh
```

As you can see the permissions on both the scripts is same and the interpreters used in both scripts is same, I'm stuck in figuring out what's causing the issue.

The shell script's code can be found here: [check_disk.sh](https://pastebin.com/n8bghC5b)

[nagios_check_files_age.sh](https://pastebin.com/niPexwqq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run visudo and look for a line with the nagios username. Someone may have given restricted sudo permissions. If you see a line like the following you can add /usr/localcw/bin/check_disk.sh to the list

visudo

```
## Allows nagios user to run below commands
nagios ALL=/usr/localcw/bin/nagios_check_files_age.sh
```

added to list

visudo

```
## Allows nagios user to run below commands
nagios ALL=/usr/localcw/bin/nagios_check_files_age.sh, /usr/localcw/bin/check_disk.sh
```

After you add this to sudoers file  try your command again.

If the nagios user is not listed in sudoers file look at facls (access controls)

```
getfacl /usr/localcw/bin/check_disk.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I can't find the line "nagios ALL=/usr/localcw/bin/nagios_check_files_age.sh". I can't even find the keyword nagios in the sudoers file opened using visudo. The solution that you suggested is working. I tried the command "getfacl" for both the scripts the output is same for both.